# Async class not passing the argument

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, jsoup

My async class is throwing some errors. The line with AsyncLoadData says that I should create local variable url

```
    public void getData() {
        new AsyncLoadData(this,this).execute(url);  
    }
```

My AsyncLoadData class

```
package com.example.hay;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AsyncLoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ILoadDataListener mListener;

    public AsyncLoadData(Context context, ILoadDataListener listener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            EditText tf = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String url = params[0];
            url = tf.getText().toString();
            Document doc;   
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String title = doc.text();

            return title;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private EditText findViewById(int edittext1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mListener.complete(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mListener.loading();
    }

    public interface ILoadDataListener {
        void loading();
        void complete(String result);
    } 
}
```

As you can see the AsyncLoadData should pass the url variable.

Comment: This code is pretty broken.  1) as the compiler is telling you , there is no variable named "url" in the method "getData".  2) Your AsyncTask is broken: you may not touch UI object methods from a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared `url` somewhere else in the code before calling this line : `new AsyncLoadData(this,this).execute(url);` ?

If not, you should add line  `String url = "the value of the url you are trying to call";` just before it, otherwise the variable `url` does not exist in the `getData` method...